# Use Android WebView for PayPal checkout

Tags: android, android-webview, paypal

i cant use paypal SDK (Express Checkout Library) from business reasons, so i need to implement the checkout via webView.
i need to know how to pass the url (based on parameters like deal code, price, user email etc)
and how to return to the app after redirection page.

this is my code:

```
public class PayPalHandler extends Activity {
//The reference token that we get from initializing the MECL library
public static String _deviceReferenceToken;
private TextView mResultText;
private CheckoutButton mCheckoutButton;
private WebView _webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super .onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.paypal);
    mResultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_paypal);
    PayPalInitializer payPalInitializer = new PayPalInitializer(
            this );
    payPalInitializer.execute();
}

private class PayPalInitializer extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private static final String APP_ID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public PayPalInitializer(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super .onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mProgressDialog
                .setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        boolean success = false;
        PayPal payPal = PayPal.getInstance();
        if (payPal == null) {
            payPal = PayPal.initWithAppID(mContext, APP_ID,PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
            payPal.setLanguage("en_US");

            if (payPal.isLibraryInitialized()) {
                success = true;
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super .onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressDialog.hide();
        mProgressDialog = null;
        if (result) {
            setupButton();
        } else {
            setupButton();
            //mResultText.setText("Done!");
        }
    }
};

private void setupButton() {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.row_paypal);
    PayPal payPal = PayPal.getInstance();

    mCheckoutButton = payPal.getCheckoutButton(this , PayPal.BUTTON_194x37, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
    mCheckoutButton .setOnClickListener(mCheckoutButtonOnClickListener);
    row.addView(mCheckoutButton);
}

private static final int request = 1;
private View.OnClickListener mCheckoutButtonOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    private SharedPreferences settings;
    UserUtil user = new UserUtil(PayPalHandler.this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String price = intent.getStringExtra("price");
        String dealCode = intent.getStringExtra("dealCode");
        String token=PayPalHandler._deviceReferenceToken;
        String currentSecurityToken = settings.getString(Constants.SECURITY_TOKEN, null);
        String os = "Android";
        String provider = "paypal";
        String caltureCode = "he-IL";
        String phoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
        String androidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
        double lat = user.getSelfLocation().getLatitude();
        double lon = user.getSelfLocation().getLongitude();

        // here i need to built the string according to parameters like deal code, email, deal title etc

        String buf = "http://api.gooz.co.il/beginpurchase.ashx?request=%7b%22ReturnUrl%22%3a%22http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1295%2fSALI.Server.Web.he-IL%2fThanks.aspx%3fDealCode%3d4%22%2c%22CancelUrl%22%3a%22http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1295%2fSALI.Server.Web.he-IL%2fDealInfo.aspx%3fDealCode%3d4%22%2c%22DealUrl%22%3a%22http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1295%2fSALI.Server.Web.he-IL%2fDealInfo.aspx%3fDealCode%3d4%22%2c%22ShopperEmail%22%3a%22sagi.baron76%40gmail.com%22%2c%22CultureCode%22%3a%22he-IL%22%2c%22Device%22%3a%22android%22%2c%22Provider%22%3a%22paypal%22%2c%22ForceJson%22%3afalse%2c%22PurchaseArgs%22%3a%5b%7b%22DealCode%22%3a%224%22%2c%22Quantity%22%3a%221%22%2c%22PaymentNumber%22%3a%221%22%7d%5d%7d";

        //Construct the WebView
        _webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());


        WebViewClient webClient = new WebViewClient()
           {
               // Override page so it's load on my view only
               @Override
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
               {
                return false;
               }
           };
        //Set our view to the WebView
        _webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setContentView(_webView);

        _webView.setWebViewClient(webClient);
        _webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        _webView.loadUrl(buf);

    }
};
```

}